# Property of generic type in non-generic class

Tags: c#, generics

**Intro**

I'm working with the legacy code which contains two classes:

- I have a class which stores its value of `System.Object` type.
  (I named this class as `DomainItem`)

  - Its Identifier property refers to
    enum which holds information what a type of `DomainItem` is (in the
    context of business domain).
- There is also a class which stores these
  items as an Enumerable List. (`DomainItems`)

What's more:

- I don't want to change these classes into generic. This code is very sensitive and not covered by tests.
- In order to get `DomainItem`, I must get it from `DomainItems.Items` collection.

**Code**

The code for classes is equivalent as below:

```
public class DomainItem
{
    public Identifier Identifier { get; set; } // Readonly in the "real" code
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class DomainItems
{
    public IEnumerable<DomainItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**The question is**

How can I extend these classes using generics, to resolve type of Value property in the compile time. Is it even possible?

**Example case** might be as following:

```
DomainItem price = new DomainItem { Value = 25.20d, Identifier = Identifier.Price };
// ....
double priceValue = price.ProperValue; // generic property of type T
```

Obviously, above code is conceptual and it shows what I want to achieve. Any suggestions how to resolve that? Is it even possible?

**Edit**

My idea is to create a new `IEnumerable<DomainItem<T>>` where the collection is populated from non-generic `DomainItem` objects. Since the type of `DomainItem.Value` is known, it should be possible to make such collection somehow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no such thing as a generic property, but you could easily create a generic *method*:

```
public T GetValue<T>() { ... }

public void SetValue<T>(T value) { ... }
```

You could then check `typeof(T)` within the method to make sure that it was appropriate for your identifier, ideally having made the identifier read-only. (It would be better as a constructor argument - I wouldn't expect it to make any sense to have a domain item whose identifier changed over time.)

Alternatively, you *could* just make the type of the `Value` property `dynamic` instead of `object`, assuming you're using C# 4+ with .NET 4+. Then your example code would compile - but it would perform an implicit (dynamic) conversion to `double` at execution time. You wouldn't get much *safety* there, but it would compile...

Comment: `T GetValue<T>` is my current approach. But I need to pass value type in generic method and I would like to avoid that. I thought about list of different generic types in `DomainItems`. See my edit note. I just wonder if it's even possible...

**Note 1**: 'Generic property' was a shorthand for property of a generic type. I renamed the title to avoid confusion.
**Note 2**: `Identifier` is readonly in the production code.

Comment: @DariuszWozniak: What do you mean by "I need to pass value type in generic method"? Your goals still really aren't clear - you say that you *don't* want to make a generic class, but then you're talking about `IEnumerable<DomainItem<T>>` which suggests that it *is* generic...

Comment: By calling `GetValue<T>`, I have to pass T param which is not safe - what if type of `Value` is not castable or convertible (dependend on the logic) to type of `T`?
`IEnumerable<DomainItem<T>>` is just a conceptual code. I know it's not possible to have such collection within non-generic class and I don't know how could I store items with different types there, but I tried to simplify my thoughts (hah! :))... Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: @DariuszWozniak: It sounds like the type is only known at *execution* time, so it's impossible to make it safe at compile time. The best you can hope for is an exception at execution time, due to specifying the type you expect it to be... which is exactly what that generic method will give you.

Comment: @JonSkeet should it not be: public T GetValue<T>(); you said its a generic method not property, thus it needs '();' :-)

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned it: you can add a constraint, e.g. `public T GetProperty<T>() where T : ISomeInterface` to ensure type-safety.